# Can we call this singleton?

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

I have a class with the following structure:

```
class Something 
{

 private static $_instance = null;

 final public function __construct()
 {
   //(...)
   try 
   {
     //(...)
   }
   catch(Exception $e) 
   {
     //(...)
   }
 }
 public static function getInstance() 
 {
   if (self::$_instance === null) 
   {
    self::$_instance = new self;
   }

   return self::$_instance;
 }
 private function __clone()
 {
   //empty
 }

} //end of class
```

Is it correct and precise to say that, on this class, we have applied a **Singleton Design Pattern**?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: some statements are missing for it to be singleton

Comment: 1) You don't do anything to make that `$_instance` 2) `__clone()` is not supposed to be static.

Comment: Ups... I will edit my code. sorry.

Comment: @BoltClock and all: I have edited my question. Does the __clone() comment still applies ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For Singelton, it's required that constructor is declared private and class has 'getter' method, most common getInstance(), that you've already implemented.

Comment: @usoban - So I just need to change the scope of the constructor to private? Or better, should I have `final static private function __construct();`

Comment: @MEM: `private function __construct()` is enough, you can't override a private member so it's implied to be final.

Comment: @BoltClock: but I still can extend it right ? Isn't that an issue somehow? (sorry for this dummy questions. :s)

Comment: @MEM and you will still need to make the public static method that creates and/or returns the singleton instance. The reason for making __construct private is so that "$foo = new Something();" will throw an error. The singleton instance should not be made with a new statement, but rather a separate public static method. example here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php

Comment: @MEM: Yes, you can, you just can't override the constructor.

Comment: @all - thank you all for your patience. :) I didn't know that the php manual has this OOP documentation. :s Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @MEM extending singleton classes gets very sticky. The static singleton getter method will pull the instance variable from the class that it was originally declared in. the static instance variable would also maintain its value from where it was originally declared. unless you do some creative writting, or only have one object of this class or it's extensions at a time, I don't believe it is recommended.

Comment: @dqhendricks: It seems that this pattern could play a role if you want to have one database connection for multiple objects to play with. But this was a matter of curiosity and not related to a specific implementation. Thanks again.